# debugging: function to create multiple lags for multiple columns (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create multiple lags of multiple variables, so I thought writing a function would be helpful. My code throws a warning ("Truncating vector to length 1 ") and false results:

```
library(dplyr)
time <- c(2000:2009, 2000:2009)
x <- c(1:10, 10:19)
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
df <- data.frame(id, time, x)



three_lags <- function (data, column, group, ordervar) {
  data <- data %>% 
    group_by_(group) %>%
    mutate(a = lag(column, 1L, NA, order_by = ordervar),
            b = lag(column, 2L, NA, order_by = ordervar),
            c = lag(column, 3L, NA, order_by = ordervar)) 
  }

df_lags <- three_lags(data=df, column=x, group=id, ordervar=time) %>%
  arrange(id, time)
```

Also I wondered if there might be a more elegant solution using `mutate_each`, but I didn't get that to work either. I can of course just write a long code with a line for each new lagged variable, but Id like to avoid that.

EDIT:

akrun's dplyr answer works, but takes a long time to compute for large data frames. The solution using `data.table` seems to be more efficient. So a dplyr or other solution that also allows the be implemented for several columns & several lags is still to be found.

EDIT 2:

For multiple columns and no groups (e.g. "ID") the following solution seems very well suited to me, due to its simplicity. The code may of course be shortened, but step by step:

```
df <- arrange(df, time)

df.lag <- shift(df[,1:24], n=1:3, give.names = T)  ##column indexes of columns to be lagged as "[,startcol:endcol]", "n=1:3" sepcifies the number of lags (lag1, lag2 and lag3 in this case)

df.result <- bind_cols(df, df.lag)
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Ill just have to read up on `data.table` to be able to manipulate it correctly and thought for others who - like me - aren't very skilled programmers `dplyr` solutions are easier to comprehend

Comment: I updated with the `data.table` solution in case there are many columns you want to do the `shift`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `shift` from `data.table` which can take multiple values for 'n'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(time), c("a", "b", "c") := shift(x, 1:3) , id][order(id, time)]
```

Suppose, we need to do this on multiple columns

```
df$y <- df$x
setDT(df)[order(time), paste0(rep(c("x", "y"), each =3), 
                c("a", "b", "c")) :=shift(.SD, 1:3), id, .SDcols = x:y]
```

---

The `shift` can also be used in the `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, time) %>% 
  do(data.frame(., setNames(shift(.$x, 1:3), c("a", "b", "c"))))
#    id  time     x     a     b     c
#   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1      1  2000     1    NA    NA    NA
#2      1  2001     2     1    NA    NA
#3      1  2002     3     2     1    NA
#4      1  2003     4     3     2     1
#5      1  2004     5     4     3     2
#6      1  2005     6     5     4     3
#7      1  2006     7     6     5     4
#8      1  2007     8     7     6     5
#9      1  2008     9     8     7     6
#10     1  2009    10     9     8     7
#11     2  2000    10    NA    NA    NA
#12     2  2001    11    10    NA    NA
#13     2  2002    12    11    10    NA
#14     2  2003    13    12    11    10
#15     2  2004    14    13    12    11
#16     2  2005    15    14    13    12
#17     2  2006    16    15    14    13
#18     2  2007    17    16    15    14
#19     2  2008    18    17    16    15
#20     2  2009    19    18    17    16
```

Comment: Thank you, that works and is clearly more efficient! I leave the question open for now

Comment: The dplyr code produces 6 columns instead of 3, despite that has the advantage of assigning sensible names to the new columns

Comment: @yoland It gives only 3 columns.  Please check if you are using the original dataset or the one after the `data.table` converted one.

Comment: @yoland The `:=` creates the new columns in the original dataset but with `%>%` it doesn't change the original dataset unless we assign it to `df` i.e. `df <- df %>%...`

Answer (score 1):

Could also create a function that will output a tibble:

```r
library(tidyverse)

lag_multiple <- function(x, n_vec){
  map(n_vec, lag, x = x) %>% 
    set_names(paste0("lag", n_vec)) %>% 
    as_tibble()
}

tibble(x = 1:30) %>% 
  mutate(lag_multiple(x, 1:5))
#> # A tibble: 30 x 6
#>        x  lag1  lag2  lag3  lag4  lag5
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  2     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  3     3     2     1    NA    NA    NA
#>  4     4     3     2     1    NA    NA
#>  5     5     4     3     2     1    NA
#>  6     6     5     4     3     2     1
#>  7     7     6     5     4     3     2
#>  8     8     7     6     5     4     3
#>  9     9     8     7     6     5     4
#> 10    10     9     8     7     6     5
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```